# colon (:) within JSON data using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm calling a web service that returns JSON. Within that JSON I have a property that holds a URL. But the colon (:) within that URL is making Gson throw a `gson.stream.MalformedJsonException` error. I know these keys and values should be wrapped

### JSON returned by web service:

```
{
   ID=15; 
   Code=ZPFgNr; 
   UserName=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xxxxxx; //<--problem
   FirstName=Joe
}
```

My Java:

```
resultData=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(0).toString();
User response = gson.fromJson(resultData, User.class);
```

**I know these keys and values should be wrapped in double quotes.** But they are not, and that seems to be the problem.

## So my question is:

Should I be encoding this JSON before deserializing it somehow? If so, how?

**or**

Should I do a find and replace on `https:` and escape the colon, If so, how would I escape the colon?

Comment: *"My JSON:"* : this isn't JSON.

Comment: JSON data is corrupted, the problem is in the service that return this data to you valid json form should be something like this :{
   ID:15, 
   Code:"ZPFgNr",
   UserName:"https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xxxxxx",
   FirstName:"Joe"
}

Comment: As @dystroy says: the input is not even valid JSON, any sane JSON parser would fail parsing such a value. Member names not being proper JSON strings etc.

Comment: Check out http://jsonlint.com/ for a quick tool to check the validity of your JSON.

Comment: Also, you say "I know these keys and values should be wrapped in double quotes": that is not the only problem. In a JSON Object, as per RFC 4627, object member names and their values should be separated by a semicolon and not an equal sign (ie, `:` and not `=`). You can of course hack that input into valid JSON, but you had better complain to the service provider which pretends that output to be valid JSON at all.

Comment: @dystroy your "comment" isn't HELPFUL.

Comment: @capdragon Your webservice isn't returning JSON but something else. Find what it returns and parse it. But don't try to use gson to do that.

Comment: @dystroy (+1) Now that's something I can take to the bank. Unfortunately, It's supposed to be returning JSON as the webmethod has `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` And when I call this service using JQuery I get the JSON back nicely. But I think you're on to something and I will investigate it further. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON uses commas to separate attributes, colon to separate the attribute name from the attribute value, and double quotes around the names and the values. This is not valid JSON.

Here's valid JSON:

```
{
   "ID" : "15", 
   "Code" : "ZPFgNr",
   "UserName" : "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xxxxxx",
   "FirstName" : "Joe"
}
```

Comment: You're right. Strange how I did not catch that, and neither did [this](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter) json formatter.

Comment: When I paste your JSON into this page, check the "validate" checkbox, and click Proceed, it clearly states it's invalid and gives you errors.

Comment: Yeah, but the only errors it gives are `Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 2]`

Comment: That's sufficient to make the JSON invalid. If you had fixed the quote errors and revalidated it, it would have told you all the other errors, until you finally get to valid JSON.

Comment: @capdragon there is the possibility to "mangle" your invalid JSON into valid JSON, ie parseable by a sane JSON parser, this is writeable and SO can even write it for you, but believe me: you had better complain to the provider, which doesn't even seem to know what JSON is. Honestly.

Comment: @fge That would be Microsoft. I mean I developed the web service but I told it to respond the User class in JSON format. I'll investigate this further.