# GSON (or) JSON to contentvalues with array of arrays

Tags: arrays, json, sqlite, gson

I am trying to get a fusiontables sql response into an sqlite db in android. jsonlint.com says the object is valid JSON.  But, the arrays in "rows" are not recognized as JsonArrays or JSONArrays.  The number of rows in an sql response can vary.  A sample response is below. I would appreciate any help in pointing me in the right direction for a solution.  Even helping me to ask a better question.  I am stumped!

```
{
"columns":"[Text, Number, Location, Date, ma, mb, mc, md, me, mf, mg, mh, mi, Xtid, JTid]",

"kind":"fusiontables#sqlresponse",

"rows":"[
[Text, 1.0, 33.2, -81.2, 2013-04-29T20:34:31.518-04:00, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 100.0], 
[Text, 3.0, 33.2, -81.2, 2013-04-29T20:43:43.257-04:00, 24.0, 23.0, 18.0, 19.0, 54.0, 21.0, 31.0, 45.0, 32.0, 29.7, 58.1], 
[Text, 5.0, 33.2, -81.2, 2013-05-01T06:58:09.801-04:00, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 100.0], 
[Text, 3.0, 33.2, -81.2, 2013-05-02T05:32:04.970-04:00, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 100.0]
]"

}


//************ code
String json = SyncResponse.toString();
JsonObject root = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println("root" + root);  //this is where I got the JSON output listed above
```

Comment: I don't understand... how does your JSON response look exactly? I mean, not after parsing it, but like you receive it... What's your class `SyncResponse`, and what's the result of `SyncResponse.toString()`?

Comment: SyncResponse is the sqlresponse from a fustiontables sqlGet query.  What I posted is exactly what the response was. I just found this mention of the issue, I guess it is not fixed yet. [Fusiontables issue 545](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=545)

Comment: ok, so I understand you CANNOT change the JSON response as I said in my answer and you have to parse the JSON response as you wrote it, right?

Comment: Correct. Is there a Gson method or do I need to use String?

Comment: Yes there's something you can do, I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in `rows` is not recognized as an array because it's not an array!

You have double quotes before and after the square brackets: `"[...]"`, that's to say, you have just a string... This string contains the representation of a JSON array, but it can't be seen as an array...

A correct JSON response in your case should be something like the following. Note that all the values that are strings are written with double quotes, but the arrays (and numbers) are not surronded by double quotes...

```
{
    "columns": [ "Text", "Number", "Location", "Date", "ma", "mb", "mc", "md", "me", "mf", "mg", "mh", "mi", "Xtid", "JTid" ],
    "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
    "rows": [
        [ "Text", 1, 33.2, -81.2, "2013-04-29T20:34:31.518-04:00", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100],
        [ "Text", 3, 33.2, -81.2, "2013-04-29T20:43:43.257-04:00", 24, 23, 18, 19, 54, 21, 31, 45, 32, 29.7, 58.1 ],
        [ "Text", 5, 33.2, -81.2, "2013-05-01T06:58:09.801-04:00", 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 100],
        [ "Text", 3, 33.2, -81.2, "2013-05-02T05:32:04.970-04:00", 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 100]
    ]
}
```

---

EDIT: First of all, note that as I said before, your JSON response in not valid... well, better said, it's valid but it's not representing the JSON elements correctly, but it's representing them as just strings...

That said, I came up with the following workaround:

First of all you need a class to *wrap* your JSON response, in your case something like:

```
public class Response {
    public String columns;
    public String kind;
    public String rows;
}
```

Then you have to parse your response with (assuming you have your JSON response in a String `jsonString`):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
```

Now you have a class `Response` with 3 attributes representing the 3 strings in your JSON response (`columns`, `kind` and `rows`).

Now you have to *re-parse* those strings, like this:

```
Type listOfStringsType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
List<String> columns = gson.fromJson(response.columns, listOfStringsType);
```

With this, you have a `List<String> columns` containing all the values: `"Text", "Number", "Location", "Date", "ma", ...`

Lastly you have to do somethig similar with the columns, but in this case it's not a list, but a list of lists:

```
Type listOfListsOfStringsType = new TypeToken<List<List<String>>>() {}.getType();
List<List<String>> rows = gson.fromJson(response.rows.replace(":", "-"), listOfListsOfStringsType);
```

Note that this time I've added `.replace(":", "-")` because otherwise you'll get an error, because `:` is interpreted by GSON as an special character (see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083365/colon-within-json-data-using-gson)).

Once you've done all of this, you'll have all your values in lists of strings, and you'll be able to parse these values and store them in your classes as you wish...

Obviously this is not the most beautiful way, but it's a good workaround taking into account the difficulty of the situation...

Comment: Thanks MikO, I would appreciate help with parsing with GSON. I can parse the whole thing as a JsonObject.  I will add the code for parsing.